# 'Right' is to 'Integrity' as 'Just' is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

Or put another way, if integrity means doing the right thing when no one is looking what is doing the just thing when no one is looking? As I understand it being *right* is a qualitative trait, while being *just* is a quantitative trait.

Comment: Can you administer justice when no one else is involved?

Comment: For all that it’s asking for a word, this seems much more a question about ethics than about English usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest word I can think of is "impartiality".

From Wikipedia:

> Impartiality is a principle of justice holding that decisions should be based on objective criteria, rather than on the basis of bias, prejudice, or preferring the benefit to one person over another for improper reasons.

Comment: Thanks, this and/or impartialness is what I was looking for. p.s. I added the definition for others, it should show up once my edit is approved.

Comment: You're welcome. *Impartialness* is a word? I see that it is in the dictionary, and is a synonym of *impartiality* that is very rarely used.

Answer (score 3):

Justice, or fairness.

I am not sure what you mean by justice being a quantitative trait, though. One could make the case for (or against) relativism in judging both the integrity and the justice of actions or individuals.

Comment: The quantitative bit was probably more about Philosophy than English. I think justice as a quantitative trait is pretty straight forward. When a debt is owed it is just that it is repaid with the exact amount agreed upon when the loan was taken. The hard part comes in when the debt can't be precisely repaid. "An eye for an eye" takes the value from the criminal in the same way value was taken from the victim however the victim's eye isn't restored through this action.

Answer (score 3):

As odd as it may seem, i'd suggest "righteousness", here.

"His sense of righteousness was so great that when he resigned, he spent all his political capital guaranteeing that the sole qualified candidate for his replacement -- a black man -- would succeed him as head of the department.  He did this, knowing full well that he could never return to work among the tight-knit Houston business community."

Answer (score 1):

Truthfully, I would say *Law* – if a person is said to have integrity for having done the "right" thing, they might be considered just for having upheld the law. A person who is just yet does not have integrity might be said to follow the letter of the law, and not the spirit.

Actually, I think of integrity as being or staying truthful, in words or to oneself and others. People with integrity do what they say they are going to do, they come through where they promised they would – if that involves upholding the law, or ensuring impartial fairness then we can call them just as well.

… just as well, really …

(sorry, couldn't resist)